# Add gcloud "Google Auth Library" to App Access Control on Google Workspace Admin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I use `gcloud auth application-default login` to authenticate my local applications to Google Cloud Platform services.

One of them is a Python app that performs a query on many BigQuery tables and they work well except for one Table, which its values come from a Drive Spreadsheet (if you go in the table details on the Console it has the link to the drive spreadsheet).

I did some research and found that, in order for it to work, I have to explicitly inform the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. So I did like this and it worked for production environemnt since the credentials are loaded from Kubernetes Workload Identity:

```
credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
])
```

But for running it locally I need to specify the scopes to my `gcloud auth application-default login` like this:

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

I've ran the command and was prompted with the authorization issue:

```
Access blocked: Authorization Error

myuser@domain.com
Access to your account data is restricted by policies within your organization. Please contact the administrator of your organization for more information.
If you are a developer of Google Auth Library, see error details.
Error 400: admin_policy_enforced
```

[image]

This error happens because the Google Workspace Admin restricts access to all applications , except the ones whitelisted at "App Access Control" section.

I contacted my Workspace admin so we went to the "App Access Controll" to add the `gcloud` to the Apps whitelist. We tried to search anything related to Google like "Google Cloud Platform" or "Google Auth Library" to add to the whitelist, but there isn't anything. I tried removing the restriction and it works, but it's  not acceptable for our security standards.

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am in a similar boat - different error but same login process when providing google workspace scopes.

Comment: @thomas not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this as well and I was able to get it working, though it's a weirdly obscure process.
In the Access Blocked message, click the "error details" link and in the popup there will be a string like:

```
Error 400: admin_policy_enforced
Request details: access_type=offline response_type=code redirect_uri=http://localhost:8085/ state=foo code_challenge_method=S256 client_id=bar-baz.apps.googleusercontent.com code_challenge=quux scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/zowie
```

Note the `client_id=bar-baz.apps.googleusercontent.com` string. You only need the `bar-baz` part (it's actually like 45 characters long). With that in hand, open your Google Workspace admin console and from the top-left-side hamburger menu, navigate to Security --> API Controls --> App Access Control --> Configured apps / View list --> Add app --> Oauth App Name Or Client ID. Plonk the client ID into the search box and it should return the Google Auth Library. From there, proceed through the trust process. Afterwards you should be able to `gcloud auth` without problems.